# mantel.test (package: cultevo)

Tags: r, permutation, vegan

I am running into some problems and was wondering if you could help me out.

I have two data.frames, one for species data and another for water quality data. I have converted my water quality dataset to u-scores, as there is "censoring" present. However, due to sampling irregularities, I select/run each water quality variable separately when I actually run the Mantel tests.

I am able to compute my distance matrices for both data.frames (i.e., log Bray-Curtis for species and Euclidean distance for the water quality variable), then perform a Mantel test using:

```
Distance.ln.bray.curtis <- vegdist(log1p(species_abundance))
Distance.euclidean = dist(explanatory_variable, method = "euclidean")
mantel.rtest(Distance.ln.bray.curtis, Distance.euclidean, nrepet = 9999)
```

But then I realized.. I have to permute the observations within each site (I have 28 sites) as this is recommended within my statistics book. This is where I am stuck, as there are no resources that I have found that have been helpful to do "within permutations" in R.

I have seen that the "cultevo" package can do perform one **or more** Mantel permutation tests, which is what I need to do. But I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing this. Would I have to reinsert the site #'s within the distance matrices? If someone could provide examples, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you read the manual page for `mantel.rtest` (I'm assuming you are using the one in package `ade`)? Specifically the part where the argument `nrepet=` is defined as "the number of permutations". All mantel tests involve permuting the distance matrices (i.e. the rows).

Comment: Yes, I did use mantel.rtest from the package "ade", but it appears that this package cannot do "within permutations by site". That's why I am trying to move to the mantel.test from the package "cultevo" as it contains (...groups = ). I have read the manual page for "cultevo", but I had a hard time understanding how to incorporate my sites so it would know which specific rows to permutate.